Map domain entities using AutoMapper.ProjectTo and clean architecture approach
We have a mid-size project. Two projects in solution, API and Domain.
Domain contains services with business logic. We don't use repositories. Just call DbContext directly from services (that's fine for us).
In API project we have controllers and DTOs to be returned from APIs. We use AutoMapper to map domain entities to DTOs.
Some of GET methods in controllers look like
public async Task<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
{
  return await dbContext.Customer
    .Where(c => c.Type == "Existing" && c.IsActive)
    .ProjectTo<CustomerDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
}

I like the idea of clean architecture and want to keep business logic in services (checks for Type and IsActive flag).
I see 3 possible options:

move the whole query to service that returns List<CustomerDto>.
move query without ProjectTo to service returning List<Customer> and do mapping in controller.
make service return IQuerable<Customer> with all where conditions applied. And apply ProjectTo in controller.

Don't really like either of these options.

DTO class doesn't belong to domain, and should be in API next to controller
no benefits from ProjectTo. EF will load full Customer object from database
returning IQuerable from service looks weird. or maybe not so?

What is the "less evil" option that you would choose?

Considering clean architecture principles and the goal of maintaining separation of concerns. My recommendation is a hybrid approach of all your options:

Service Layer: The service layer should encapsulate business logic and data access but avoid dealing with DTOs directly. It should return domain entities or collections of them (e.g., List).
Controller Layer: The controller layer should handle the mapping from domain entities to DTOs using AutoMapper's ProjectTo.

Code Sample:
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public CustomerService(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<Customer>> GetActiveExistingCustomersAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Customers
            .Where(c => c.Type == "Existing" && c.IsActive)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}

public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CustomerService _customerService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CustomersController(CustomerService customerService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<CustomerDto>>> GetCustomers()
    {
        var customers = await _customerService.GetActiveExistingCustomersAsync();
        //var customerDtos = _mapper.Map<List<CustomerDto>>(customers);

var customerDtos = await customers
            .ProjectTo<CustomerDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(customerDtos);
    }


}

This approach helps with:

Separation of Concerns: Keeps business logic in the service layer and presentation logic in the controller.
Single Responsibility Principle: Each layer has a clear responsibility, making the code easier to maintain and test.
Flexibility: The controller can still leverage AutoMapper, without exposing IQueryable.


Thanks for your answer. I think you described by option #2, where service returns a collection of domain entities. In this case, I lose the benefit of ProjectTo which allows to load from DB only columns required to CustomerDto and not the whole Customer object.

btw, offtopic. returning Ok(customerDtos) from controller method brakes type safety. You can put anything you want into Ok() method, even if it's not List<CustomerDto>.
Better return just object itself. It will be implicitly converted to ActionResult<List<CustomerDto>>. It helps with avoid errors where you see one object in Swagger, but actual response is different

@user1614543 check my edit in my answer in CustomerController.GetCustomers
i have added ProjectTo case as well. and regarding your second comment that can be done as well
